# What is the universally accepted way to provide inputs to JUnit Test Suite

Tags: java, excel, junit4

I have designed `JUnit` Test Suite with required values hard-coded in the code itself. Each time if there is any changes, I need to open the project and do the modifications. To provide input from external file, I am using excel sheets, which can be easily designed. The excel file is having some drop down menu items also, which tells about the test cases needs to be executed. The excel sheet is also having some text box in which user has to fill the values before running test suite.
But the excel is not platform independent .

Is there any better way which is universally accepted and platform independent to provide inputs to JUnit Test Suite?

Answer (score 1):

One of the core concepts about test driven development is that you run all test cases, all of the time in an automated way.  Having a user use excel to choose test cases and enter data breaks this model.

You could read from a file to drive your test cases, but perhaps your tests need to be redefined to be data independent.  Also all of them should run every time you run JUnit.

Just yesterday I used random data to perform a test...here is an example:

```
@Test
public void testIntGetter() {
  int value = random.getNextInt();
  MyObj obj = new MyObj(value);

  assertEquals(value,obj.getMyInt());

}
```

While this is an overly simple example it does test the functionality of the class while being data independent.

Once you decide to break the test driven development/JUnit model, then your question is not really applicable.  This is fine to use a tool for other purposes, but your specific question is incorrect.

It is best to have data reside in code, with some exceptions testing is independent of the data as my example shows.  Most of those exceptions are edge cases that should reside in code.  For example a method that takes a String parameter, should be tested against null, and empty string and a non-empty String.

If the value of a parameter reveals a defect in the code, the code should be fixed and that value should be a permanent member of the collection of test conditions.

Comment: Before starting the test suite, the user has to fill the required info in excel file. After that test suite will run automatically. No issues.
Also you forget to put the example at the end. Please do the necessary changes.

Comment: Agree with you but still my question is unanswered :( Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Do I understand you right, that the main thing here is to find a way that makes it easy for a tester to key in test data?
It's not so much about writing a test case, right?

Well, that issue happens in many different projects. One, for example, is to have users key in some basic values in a database table.

There're many ways to solve that. A lot of people use Excel, even more use MS-Access-Forms, Sharepoint or, if they're more familiar with Web-Tools, they end up building web sites.
In the end, your way and the tool you use depends on yours and the testers knowledge and the number of interfaces you have to build and maintain. In my company we ended up with some configurable web sites that is independant of any 3rd party software licence (which was a main requirement in our case).

The only tool, where one should be very careful, is Excel. If you need only a few interfaces, lets say 10-20, Excel for me can still be handled. When it gets more, than the maintenance of Excel will kill you, mainly because Excel keeps programming and business logic for each interface separately. Changing the business logic menas to change all excels separately. This kills you sooner or later.

Comment: But this would also apply for any other form of a GUI: if you have to maintain 20 GUIs for testing it may be handled, if it gets more it will kill you (except for stuff which is covered by the IDE, e.g., refactoring).

Comment: Yes, absolutely. The above question could be answered independently from the Testing-context. I think, that the maintain-ability for a larger number of interfaces is what differentiates the professional tools from the rest.
But what you consider as 'professional enouth for your case' is really something that can only be answered by you. I dont think that there's more then a very generic answer to this question in general.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no universal accepted way to provide input to JUnit tests. Afaik, a unit test is often - or by definition - small (smallest testable part). Data is provided hardcoded as part of a test.

That said, I also use unit testing to conduct test of larger numerical algorithms / models, for which I sometimes have to provide, more complicated data. I provide this data via a spreadsheet too. I believe the spreadsheet is the natural GUI for this kind of tabular data.

I trigger my Java code directly from the spreadsheet using [Obba](http://www.obba.info) (disclaimer: I am the developer of Obba too, but my main open source project is a library of mathematical finance, for which I use these sheet).

My suggestion is to go both routes:

- create small (classical) unit test with predefined hardcoded data as part of your build environment.
- create bigger test with data provided via the sheet to analyse the codes behavior to input.

If possible, add a hardcoded "bigger test" to your automated test suit from time to time.

Note: There is also the concept of *parametrized unit tests* and there are tools which then generate (e.g. randomize) the parameters as part of a the testing.